# How to add Websphere Application Server Liberty Profile runtime dependencies to Maven POM?

Tags: maven, websphere-8, websphere-liberty, ibm-was

I have a restful application that I converted to a maven project. Now, I get a compile error when using `maven compile` because the java-ee/openjpa packages are not found. Below is my POM file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>portal</groupId>
  <artifactId>portal</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>developer-portal</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <serverName>dropServer</serverName>
    <serverHome>C:\wlp</serverHome>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>Liberty</id>
        <name>Liberty Repository</name>
        <url>http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
        <artifactId>was-liberty</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hard-Coded, made-up dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.nosql</groupId>
        <artifactId>nosqljson</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\javalib\db2_drivers\nosqljson.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>developer-portal</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-server</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <serverHome>${serverHome}</serverHome>
                        <serverName>${serverName}</serverName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <serverHome>${serverHome}</serverHome>
                <serverName>${serverName}</serverName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deployapp</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appArchive>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}.war</appArchive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Here is the particular error in eclipse:

```
Missing artifact com.ibm.tools.target:was-liberty:pom:8.5.5
```

And in CLI:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project developer-portal: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project developer-porta
>   l:developer-portal:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
>   com.ibm.tools.target:was-liberty:pom:8.5.5 in
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/ maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

References:

1. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=e98d726e-6f5d-470c-a042-dd8b41384235
2. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/localrepo.htm?lang=en

Comment: Is this pom matching the error you are getting because I can see no reference in your pom to `com.ibm.tools.target:was-liberty:pom:8.5.0`but I see one for 8.5.5?

Comment: Sorry no, I was fooling around. I did use 8.5.5 at first. EDIT - Updated to the correct error.

Answer (score 7):

The problem was maven was only looking at the central repository. To add IBM's repository, you need the following in your POM:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Liberty</id>
        <name>Liberty Repository</name>
        <url>http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/</url>
    </repository>  
 </repositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two things to do: setup the IBM repository and add the appropriate dependencies to the POM. You can take a look at the links below for instructions on doing both.

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/setibmrep.htm
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/localrepo.htm