# Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"

Tags: maven, portlet, websphere-liberty

WebSphere Liberty Profile supports Portlet development, as described in this tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/developing-portlet-applications-wdt-liberty-profile/. I went through the tutorial and configured the tools and created a simple portlet project. I have a view.jsp file that contains a tag lib reference:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>
```

I need to convert my project to a maven project, and when i do that i get the following error:

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0"
```

My pom.xml contains the following depencencie:

```
<!-- this was added automatically -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
    <artifactId>was-liberty</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- this was added manually, needed for Portlet class -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I suspect that some additional dependency is missing. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: **Wild guess** (I don't know much about WebShere though): the servlet `javax.portlet:portlet-api:2.0` is just the servlet specification, but the implementation is the portlet container's job - i.e. Websphere's job. Try to find the jar that contains the portlet.tld file inside Websphere's libraries and add it with `<scope>provided</scope>` to you `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find instructions for converting existing projects to Maven: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_devtools/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/convert.htm

You might be missing adding the IBM repository, some references here: [How to add Websphere Application Server Liberty Profile runtime dependencies to Maven POM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25265840/how-to-add-websphere-application-server-liberty-profile-runtime-dependencies-to/25288566#25288566)